# Java String parameter in Oracle sql developer

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to use some java function in Oracle SQL Developer. But Im having some troubles with java String parameter. I know my code does nothing with this String. It will be.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "StringTest" AS
public class StringTest
{ 
    public static int test(String a)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
/
```

Which returns:

> Java Source StringTest created

Then:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_STRING(input1 in char) return number
as LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'StringTest.test(String) return int';
```

> Function F_STRING compiled

Now when I try to execute my function:

```
SELECT F_STRING("some_text") FROM MyTable;
```

> ORA-00904: "some_text": invalid identifier
>
> 904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

When I try using single quote instead of **"** I get this:

> ORA-29531: no method test in class StringTest
>   29531. 00000 -  "no method %s in class %s"
>   *Cause:    An attempt was made to execute a non-existent method in a
>              Java class.
>   *Action:   Adjust the call or create the specified method.

Same thing happens when I use **varchar2** instead of **char**.
Im sure Im missing something very simple, but can't find solution for like few hours and it already drives me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you publishing java method in oracle you have to use full class name. (Canonical Name).

`int` - is ok ,
`String` - is not ok.

Change this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_STRING(input1 in char) return number
    as LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'StringTest.test(String) return int';
```

to this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_STRING(java.lang.String in char) return number
as LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'StringTest.test(java.lang.String) return int';
```

Comment: Was trying this at the beginning, but probably made some typo so I abandoned the idea..
Works even without `F_STRING(java.lang.String in char)`
`F_STRING(input1 in char)` is fine

Comment: For primitives types like `int`, `char` there is no conical path. For class, this (String, Char) path is required.   But I don't understand why it's work with F_STRING(input1 in char).  In Oracle varchar2 = varchar =~(almost) = CHAR.
In java String != char.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle will not tolerate `String` use `java.lang.String` instead.

..Also

Not overuse " sign since this forces you to use exact case call to object, since this is not a big problem with java source it may be with other objects.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED stringtest AS
public class StringTest
{
    public static int test(String a)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_STRING(input1 in char) return number
as LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'StringTest.test(java.lang.String) return java.lang.Intiger';


SELECT F_STRING('some_text') FROM dual;
```